# can I post json string only (without "name=") using form?

Tags: html, json, forms, wechat

I am trying to post json data to an URL which I have no control. The API document says only json data is accepted. I am thinking whether I can use html form to make it easier.

There are lots of posts here in regards of how to "post json data using form", none of them applies my situation. The problem is, as far as I know, if you post data using form, the thing being post is always "name=value", however, the API wants only "value". That is to say, even though I can `JSON.stringify` `input` values to a JSON string, I still need to post it with a "name", which the API doesn't want.  So this is my question, can I actually post values only using form?

Update: the [API document](http://qydev.weixin.qq.com/wiki/index.php?title=%E5%8F%91%E6%B6%88%E6%81%AF)

What it says in the API is very vague to me. Key infos are:
1)When calling the interface, use HTTPS protocal and JSON data package, the data package doesn't need to be encrypted.

2)HTTPS request method: POST
https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/message/send?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

For ACCESS_TOKEN I need to get it using some password and it expires in 2 hours.

3)If message sent successfully, it returns:

```
{
   "errcode": 0,
   "errmsg": "ok",
   "invaliduser": "UserID1",
   "invalidparty":"PartyID1",
   "invalidtag":"TagID1"
}
```

Comment: Json is key pair, what you are looking for apparently is plain text

Comment: Are you saying I need to use "text/plain" for the form's enctype?

Comment: you can post a json string as just the string. post doesn't REQUIRE a key=value pair in the post body. but if you're using something like PHP on the server, then you have to use key=value, because the key is required to populate $_POST with the value. you can always read the raw value from the input directly, e.g. `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');`. An html form by itself will NOT submit any value which has no name, so you'd need javascript to build your name-less post.

Comment: @shenkwen Probably, it would be easier to help if URL or other things was provided

Comment: That URL need a dynamic ACCESS_TOKEN to access, so I can't provide it. But if you read Chinese, you can see this API dcoument: http://qydev.weixin.qq.com/wiki/index.php?title=%E5%8F%91%E9%80%81%E6%8E%A5%E5%8F%A3%E8%AF%B4%E6%98%8E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The work to allow [JSON formatted data to be directly generated from a form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) has been discontinued.

To make the request you will need to use either:

- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to the API (which requires that [permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), including support for a [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), is granted by the API)
- XMLHttpRequest to a proxy
- Server side code

Any of these could use an HTML form to collect the data before using it to generate the request to the third party API.

Comment: I actually tried using $.ajax but it returns a cross domain error, just as you said. I still need a little clarification though, when I use $.ajax to send the data, although I can't see what the URL returns due to cross domain issue, but the URL does get my post data, doesn't it?

Comment: You can see the complete request using the Network tab in the developer tools of your browser. Since you will be sending the data formatted as JSON you will have set the content type to one that can't be generated by a plain HTML form. That triggers a preflight OPTIONS request to ask permission. Since the service isn't using CORS to grant permission, it will be denied so the POST request is never sent.